# How to solve the problem of caching fonts and files in css?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I use the `font icon` to display the icons, but when I update the `fonts` and add a new icon to the font, because the fonts are `cached`, they are difficult to display and the cache must be emptied.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sass` in your source. Use its `Random()` feature, as follows:
Every time the source is built, its `version` will be changed and the browser will call it `without cache`.

```css
$version: random(9999);
$path: /YOUR_FOTNS_PATH

@font-face {
  font-family: "font-icon";
  src: url("#{$path}/fonticon.eot?v=#{$version}");
  src: url("#{$path}/fonticon.eot?#iefix&v=#{$version}")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("#{$path}/fonticon.ttf?v=#{$version}") format("truetype"),
    url("#{$path}/fonticon.woff?v=#{$version}") format("woff"),
    url("#{$path}/fonticon.svg?#afam&v=#{$version}") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Your generated css will be:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "font-icon";
  src: url('fonticon.eot?v=3889');
  src: url('fonticon.eot?#iefix&v=3889') format("embedded-opentype"), url('fonticon.ttf?v=3889') format("truetype"), url('fonticon.woff?v=3889') format("woff"), url('fonticon.svg?#afam&v=3889') format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```